# Android retrofit async (concept)

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-spinner, retrofit

I was doing a form who loads a countries list and when user selects any of them it loads the cities list. (Using Spinners)

When I load the countries I set as `setOnItemSelectedListener` a class implementing `OnItemSelectedListener`. As I need to update the cities list I sent the `View` object in the constructor of the listener class. (To get the spinner when needed)

In the listener class in the `onItemSelected` method I used retrofit again to get the cities. Everything is working fine...

The problem is inside the `call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {` class in the `onResponse` async method. When I try `(Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);` it returns null, but if I use the same line in the constructor when receives the view, it returns the spinner fine.

Why is that happening?

Thx a lot

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the code snippet from your application?